# NSPredicate predicateWithFormat @"ANY relationship.attribute == %@" throws exception

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to display my Core Data info in TableViews, the first TableView displays all the regions in which photos have been taken, when you select a region, a segue is performed to the second TableView that displays all photos taken in that region. But when I select a region the compiler throws an exception

This is the relationship between Photo entity and Region entity [Photo]<<->[Region]. The Photo has various attributes that are non relevant for this question and the Region has one attribute that is the "name" of the region called name. the Predicate I use to try to fetch the photos is the following [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY region.name ==[c] %@", self.region.name]. I pass the Region entity that was selected and the context in the prepareForSegue method in the previous ViewController.

The expected result would be that the TableView displays all photos taken on that particular Region. The exception thrown by the compiler is this CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:  , keypath name not found in entity  with userInfo of (null).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First question, sry for not formatting the code. And Just in case, I know that self.region is not nil.

Comment: If relationships are established you don't need to refetch the data. Just get the photos from the relationship.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? Sorry very new to the hole iOS development, especially core data.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the Core Data model and the code of the NSManagedObject+CoreDataProperties subclasses

Comment: I solved partly because of what you said, I just pass the Region in the prepare to segue and instead of refetching just set and array of photos as the region.photos and is working. Thanks a lot!